# How to split routes into separate file?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Hi all im trying to split my routes into a separate file but in dotnet its proving to be much more of a hassle compared to other setups like NodeJS and PHP.

my program.cs stored in /src

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using DotEnv.Core;
using TaskTracker;

new EnvLoader()
    .AddEnvFile("../env/.env")
    .Load();

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
var app = builder.Build();

app.UseRouting();

IndexRoutes.MapRoutes(app.Endpoints);
    
app.Run("http://"+EnvReader.Instance["HOST"]+":"+EnvReader.Instance["PORT"]+"");
```

index.cs stored in /src/Routes

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing;

namespace TaskTracker
{
    public static class IndexRoutes
    {
        public static void MapRoutes(IEndpointRouteBuilder endpoints)
        {
            endpoints.MapGet("/", context => context.Response.WriteAsync("Hello planet earth"));
        }
    }
}
```

dotnet run watch is giving `/app/Program.cs(14,27): error CS1061: 'WebApplication' does not contain a definition for 'Endpoints' and no accessible extension method 'Endpoints' accepting a first argument of type 'WebApplication' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [/app/TaskTrackerAPI.csproj]`

Where am I going wrong??

Comment: You don't say, but I'm guessing that the error points to this line `IndexRoutes.MapRoutes(app.Endpoints)`. The error is saying that the `WebApplication` class (which you don't show) doesn't have an `Endpoints` property. What are you trying to do? What do you expect from your code?

Comment: @Flydog57 You are correct that I didn't specify that line exactly, as technically the error message already did in the form of the line number. The WebApplication class I am using is this one https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.builder.webapplication?view=aspnetcore-7.0 Bassically what I am trying to achieve here is a simple api app, which stores the routes in separate files which is best practice for things like readability and such. So I have my index.cs where I want to setup some basic routes, which I want the main program.cs file to use so they are accessible.

Comment: Ok so it turns out the correct way to go about this was to simply pass the app (WebApplication class instance) to my Maproutes() and use that instead of endpoints and from there I could call MapGet on app as if I was doing it in the main program file.